# Conceptually, what makes a convincing case for researchers to add an extra predictor to their models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, modeling

Here is a thought-example to make things easily understandable: Let's pretend that researchers often use a paradigm where half of a series of objects are shown to participants' left eye and the other half it is shown to the right. I have demonstrated that there is a difference between the expected accuracy of presenting to the two eyes.

I, therefore, say that people should not only model the accuracy based on which type of stimuli, say face or house, shown but also based on which eye/position the object is shown. This almost always leads to better models when evaluated for instance by AIC across several experiments.

However, several researchers have met this point with basically a "who cares?". In their eyes, as long as they are counterbalancing everything. finding a difference will surely not be wrong and modelling fever things is by definition easier than to model more.

I am hoping to demonstrate that modelling the additional variable is not only the right thing to do but that it is also better for the researchers themselves. Currently, I am trying to do that by a simulation that shows that ChiSq consistently is higher when you include eye/position.

I am simulating some data and performing two sets of comparisons:

## a) A test that does not take pos into accout

```
lm0  <- glmer(cor~(1|participant),data=out, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
lm1  <- glmer(cor~+con+(1|participant),data=out, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
anova(lm0,lm1)
```

## b) A test  that does take pos into account

```
lm2  <- glmer(cor~+pos+(1|participant),data=out, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
lm2a  <- glmer(cor~+con+pos+(1|participant),data=out, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
test2 <- anova(lm2,lm2a)
```

And then I could, for instance, show that over 500 simulations, there is a higher amount of significant differences in case b. I.e. we more often correctly identify the small simulated difference when we take into account the position effect.

Is this method 1) legit and 2) convincing? I am not completely sure that this is the best way to compare the two approaches. Especially, that I am "setting the bar higher" in b).

I hope to be able to demonstrate that it will benefit people to take a known factor into their models and try to persuade them by showing that the power of their experiment likely will be increased. You can see some R code that generates a simulation and runs an analysis [here](https://pastebin.com/dmtmiz7W), though I am mainly interested in the conceptual level right now.

How would you approach this issue?

Thanks for reading through my long post and I hope that my question makes sense to you.

Comment: The "who cares" question is not a statistical one--it is psychophysical.  If a researcher doesn't care about a difference, it is hopeless to try to use a statistical simulation to show otherwise.  Power arguments, on the other hand, at least have the merit of being translatable into time and cost, both of which are likely to be of interest to any principal researcher.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your response. I guess that you are right that convincing people is a psychological matter, is there maybe a more fitting place to ask this question? What about the way to calculate the power, does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: Maybe I have missed your point but why not use prediction with cross-validation as a metric, and if the model that includes `pos` provides better predictions, this is prima-facie evidence to include it in your studies ?